# Inline code using Interop.CDO

Tags: c#, asp.net, com-interop, inline-code

I can't find a way to use `Interop.CDO` with inline code.

If I'm using a standard Web Application, I simply add a COM reference to `Microsoft CDO for Windows 2000 Library` and then I can use CDO:

```
CDO.Message msg = new CDO.Message();
```

I tried to import the CDO Namespace:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="CDO" %>
```

But then I have the following error:

> CS0144: Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'CDO.Message'

Is it possible to use this COM dll with inline code?

**Note**: it's a requirement to use CDO, I can't use System.Net.Mail.